# Add Id column and populate with CSV name in R forloop

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have many CSVs that I would like to create an Id column in and populate that Id column with the name of the CSV.

This is a sample of current B1.csv:

```
 Date_Time         Temp
5/5/2020 11:00       89
5/5/2020 11:30       97
5/5/2020 12:00       108
```

I would like to see:

```
 Id         Date_Time         Temp
 B1      5/5/2020 11:00       89
 B1      5/5/2020 11:30       97
 B1      5/5/2020 12:00       108
```

Code:

```
temp = list.files("C:\\Users\\kujld016\\**\\r", 
                  pattern = "*.csv", full.name=T)
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv)



for( i in seq_along(myfiles)){
  
  myfiles[[i]]$Id<-NOT sure what to do here
  write.csv(myfiles[[i]], paste0("C:\\Users\\***\\out\\",myfiles[[i]][1,1],'.csv'), row.names=F)
}
```

*I am not sure how to create a reproducible example. I have included everything I can think of that may be needed above. Thanks

Comment: `myfiles[[i]]$Id <- temp[i]`? Or maybe use a little regex if needed to extract the file name from the full file path (if that's included in `temp`)

Comment: This worked! But included the whole file path. I need to specify the CSV name within that file path and I will have it knocked out. Thanks

Comment: You could remove everything before the last `/` in the path - `file_name = sub(".*/", "", temp)` and then use `file_name[i]`.

Comment: I was able to get closer to what I needed using substr(temp[i], 75,77). However, my CSVs are number B1 - B100 so the substring specification is different depending on the digits.

Comment: If you post a few example of your file paths then I could help more effectively. The other option would be to use a new `list.files` call to complement the one you have, perhaps `file_names = list.files("C:\\Users\\kujld016\\**\\r", pattern = "*.csv", full.name = FALSE)`

Comment: Below is an example of a full file path. I have 98 of these ranging from B1 - B100. I just tried changing full.name=F and received the error: cannot open file B1.csv, no such file or directory. 
 "C:\\Users\\kujld016\\Desktop\\All\\Dissertation_Research\\XXXDataXXX\\all_data\\r/B99.csv"

Comment: You'll need to add a *new* `list.files` command. Keep your current one as-is, and use it to read in the files (which requires the full file path) - it's working great, don't change it. Add the one I gave and use it only for the `myfiles[[i]]$Id <- file_names[i]` step.

Comment: I appreciate everyone. With your help, it is now working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

infolder  <- "C:\\Users\\***\\r"
outfolder <- "C:\\Users\\***\\out"

setwd(infolder)

csvfiles <- dir(path = infolder, pattern = "\\.csv$")

for (i in csvfiles) {
  #tmpfile <- read_csv(i)
  #tmpfile$filename <- i
  #write_csv(tmpfile, file.path(outfolder, i)
  print(file.path(outfolder, i))
}
```

Comment: M. Viking, at the moment I would like to keep all CSVs separate. The 'write.csv' portion of the code will do what I need as long as I get the Id column figured out.

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the original files.. or drop them in a separate folder.. or change the name,,   filename.csv  ->   filename_mod.csv...

Comment: I have the write.csv pathway set to drop the csv files in an empty folder so that the originals are not altered.

Comment: csvfiles appears to populate with each CSV, but when I run the loop I get an error stating no such file or directory.

Comment: I believe the issue is that I am pulling and saving files outside of my working directory.

Comment: Included a `setwd()` command, and commented-out the reading and writing, and added a `print()` statement so you can test how the file path looks.